# Is it ok to change the title of a question, if the question isnt descriptive at all?

Tags: discussion

Sometimes the titles of questions arent descriptive at all. This isnt the case in most of the cases (perhaps 99% of the times the title is alright) but in some cases you have no clue what the question is about by reading the title. For example a topic like, "a question about x anime" isnt descriptive at all. Changing the title might be problematic, since you could change the intention of the asker about the question.

Is it ok to change the title of a question, if the question isnt descriptive at all?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is okay to change the title.

However, be sure to inform the OP of the question as well, and guide them to resources to improve their title writing. This way the OP can also improve their future questions.

Some good guidance on writing titles can be found [How do I write a good title?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title)

And off course you can also link to the [A&M help/how-to-ask](https://anime.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) All though I personally prefer the title guidance as referenced on [SO's help/how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 3):

That depends on what you mean. Please keep in mind that [Stack Exchange has a greater bent on individual post ownership than Wikipedia](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/03/04/the-great-edit-wars/), so the golden rule of [editing](https://english.stackexchange.com/editing) is "To clarify the meaning of a post (without changing that meaning)".

Editing a nondescript title into a descriptive one is permissible if you can interpret the question as a whole well enough to devise a title which reflects the probable intentions of the overall post. We may also incorporate information from the comments into an edit, if they accurately represent those intentions. Clarification of what was already expressed does require some amount of re-interpretation, so if you try to rewrite the title to better represent the probable intention so that people can understand the gist of the question better before clicking into it, then you should be fine. That makes it easier for people to find the question and know if they would be interested in viewing it.

However, if the post as a whole is so vague that you do not know what the question is probably meant to be, then you should probably leave the title alone, and vote to close the question instead. What we do not want to do is risk is a premature answer based on a misinterpretation of the questioner's intentions and have it rise to the top. If that happens, then it may garner premature votes and burden answers based on a correct understanding of  the question with undue competition for the top voted answer. This is not only important because it helps find the questioner find the answer they seek more easily, but also because we want questions to serve all future visitors who find our website by making search engine queries which direct them to the question. Note that that [the closure system is meant in part to compel questioners to make necessary edits that improve a post to the point where it can be practicably answerable and reopened](https://stackoverflow.blog/2013/06/25/the-war-of-the-closes/). If clarification from the questioner is needed, and you can articulate what needs to be clarified, then please [leave a comment explaining it, since that's part of why we have comments.](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).

Basically, you should try to leave the question in a better state than you found it, but not at the risk of biasing the question by adding meaning to it that was never there in the first place.